# Creating realms/clients on a domain Keycloak server is not immediately visible to a slave Keycloak node

Tags: realm, keycloak, high-availability, infinispan

We have 2 machines running `Keycloak 4.8.3.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final)` in domain mode. First of them host1 is going to run the domain controller and is going to be our master. Host2 is our slave and registers itself to the master. From our understanding, Domain mode solves this problem by providing a central place to store and publish configuration.

The first one is started by executing the command:

> /opt/keycloak/bin/domain.sh --host-config host-master.xml -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled -Djboss.node.name=host1

The second one by executing the command:

> /opt/keycloak/bin/domain.sh --host-config host-slave.xml -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.domain.master.username=slave -Djboss.domain.master.address={host1_ip} -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Djboss.node.name=host2

Both of them start successfully and the slave manages to connect to the master one. We are using a MySQL machine that both the server point to for data persistence.

First, we used the default domain.xml that comes with keycloak distribution and our initial expectations was that by creating something on host1, the changes would be propagated to the host2. Unfortunately, this did not happen. When we were creating a user, the user would appear after some time to host2. When we created a realm or a client in a realm from host1, the changes could not be seen from host2 until after we restarted both servers and the sync of info was forced.

Next step was to change the domain.xml configuration at the `infinispan` directive and make the cache replicated across all machines.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:7.0">
    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000" />
        <replicated-cache name="authenticationSessions" />
        <replicated-cache name="clientSessions" />
        <replicated-cache name="offlineClientSessions" />
        <replicated-cache name="authorization" />
        <replicated-cache name="work" />
        <replicated-cache name="keys" />
        <replicated-cache name="actionTokens"></replicated-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="realms" />
        <replicated-cache name="users" />
        <replicated-cache name="sessions" />
        <replicated-cache name="offlineSessions" />
        <replicated-cache name="loginFailures" />
        <replicated-cache name="work" />
        <replicated-cache name="realmVersions" />
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="server" aliases="singleton cluster" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000" />
        <replicated-cache name="default">
            <transaction mode="BATCH" />
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000" />
        <distributed-cache name="dist">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
            <transaction mode="BATCH" />
            <file-store />
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000" />
        <distributed-cache name="dist">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
            <transaction mode="BATCH" />
            <file-store />
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000" />
        <local-cache name="local-query">
            <object-memory size="10000" />
            <expiration max-idle="100000" />
        </local-cache>
        <invalidation-cache name="entity">
            <transaction mode="NON_XA" />
            <object-memory size="10000" />
            <expiration max-idle="100000" />
        </invalidation-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="timestamps" />
    </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

However, we have the same problems especially the issue that if you regenerate a secret for a client, the secret is not propagated to the slave host nor the other way around.

Has anybody else experience that issue and what did you do in order to resolve it? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Does a cluster between the two nodes form? INFO level messages indicate what the cluster view is. You should have two nodes in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that our cloud provider is not supporting multicast and the two servers could not find and talk to each other! I made a change to the configuration and started using TCPPING instead of PING that just uses UDP. 
I spent so much time trying to figure that out so please make sure that your provider is supporting multicast in order to just use Keycloak out of the box. Also, I found out the following article that provides information on how to setup Keycloak https://www.keycloak.org/2019/04/keycloak-cluster-setup.html. If only this article was created when I was trying to deal with this problem...